# Merge arrays by common column values in julia

Tags: julia, array-merge

Suppose we have the following 3 arrays in Julia:

`5.0  3.5
 6.0  3.6
 7.0  3.0`

`5.0  4.5
 6.0  4.7
 8.0  3.0`

`5.0  4.0
 6.0  3.2
 8.0  4.0`

I want to merge the 3 arrays in one array, by common values of the first column, summing the values of the second column. The result must be the following array:

`5.0  12
 6.0  11.5
 7.0  3.0
 8.0  7.0`

I tried `vcat` and `reduce` but I don't get the pretended result. Is there a relatively simple way to code the instructions, avoiding a time-consuming code? Thank you!

Comment: Your first columns in all 3 arrays are sorted. Is this an accident? If not, then there are algorithms that are *significantly* faster than both of those provided thus far.

Comment: Yes, the first columns are always sorted! :-) Really??

Comment: Yes, a `while` loop that simultaneously advances down the first column of all input arrays. The conditional logic will be a little messy though. I'm out of time today, but I'll try and come back and have a crack at it tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I'm curious :-)

Comment: Done. I've assumed both sort order and uniqueness since it makes it a bit less complicated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following two assumptions:

1. the first column of each input array is sorted,
2. the first column of each input array is unique,

then for most input combinations (i.e. number of input arrays, sizes of arrays), the following algorithm should significantly outperform the other answers by taking advantage of the assumptions:

```
function f_ag(x::Matrix{T}...)::Matrix{T} where {T<:Number}
    isempty(x) && error("Empty input")
    any([ size(y,2) != 2 for y in x ]) && error("Input matrices must have two columns")
    length(x) == 1 && return copy(x[1]) #simple case shortcut
    nxmax = [ size(y,1) for y in x ]
    nxarrinds = find(nxmax .> 0)
    nxrowinds = ones(Int, length(nxarrinds))
    z = Tuple{T,T}[]
    while !isempty(nxarrinds)
        xmin = minimum(T[ x[nxarrinds[j]][nxrowinds[j], 1] for j = 1:length(nxarrinds) ])
        minarrinds = Int[ j for j = 1:length(nxarrinds) if x[nxarrinds[j]][nxrowinds[j], 1] == xmin ]
        rowsum = sum(T[ x[nxarrinds[k]][nxrowinds[k], 2] for k in minarrinds ])
        push!(z, (xmin, rowsum))
        for k in minarrinds
            nxrowinds[k] += 1
        end
        for j = length(nxarrinds):-1:1
            if nxrowinds[j] > nxmax[nxarrinds[j]]
                deleteat!(nxrowinds, j)
                deleteat!(nxarrinds, j)
            end
        end
    end
    return [ z[n][j] for n = 1:length(z), j = 1:2 ]
end
```

If assumption 2 is violated, that is, the first column is not guaranteed to be unique, you can still take advantage of the sort order, but the algorithm is going to be more complicated again since you'll need to additionally look forward on each minimum index to check for duplicates. I'm not going to put myself through that pain at this point.

Also note, you could adjust the following line:

```
rowsum = sum(T[ x[nxarrinds[k]][nxrowinds[k], 2] for k in minarrinds ])
```

to this:

```
rowsum = input_func(T[ x[nxarrinds[k]][nxrowinds[k], 2:end] for k in minarrinds ])
```

and now you can input whatever function you like, and also have any number of additional columns in your input matrices.

There are probably some additional optimizations that could be added here, eg pre-allocating `z`, specialized routine when there are only two input matrices, etc, but I'm not going to bother with them.

Comment: Just a little comment: it's the first column of each array that is sorted, not the first row. I can transpose each array, anyway. Otherwise, thank you for your hard work!!

Comment: @coolsv gah! The code itself is correct, it is just my text that is wrong. I'll fix it when I'm not on phone. If my response is helpful then it would probably be a good idea to give the response an upvote (similarly for the other responses). Cheers.

Comment: Have fixed the text

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I just checked the code and indeed, it's just a matter of text... Sorry for the trouble.... Thank you for your wonderful work!!

Comment: I found it interesting the part where you mention that we can adjust the line for whatever function we like. I was thinking implementing it for calculating the mean of the values, rather than their sum ;-)

Comment: @coolsv Just FYI, if you ask a question on StackOverflow, it is considered good form to upvote any responses that are helpful (click the up arrow next to the response) and also to click the tick mark (the answer mark) next to the response that best answers the question. Looking through your profile history, you haven't clicked the tick mark on *any* of the 10 questions you have asked here. Fair warning: if you don't do this, people will eventually stop answering your questions here.

Comment: Ok I didn't know! Sorry!

Comment: The code worked perfectly with a finite number of arrays. I tried to expand use it for aggregating 500 matrices stored in an array. So I have an array of 500 arrays. How can I aggragate the 500 arrays with the function `f_ag` without listing all the 500 arrays? With the `map`or `mapslices`command?.

Comment: @coolsv This sounds like a different question, eg what's the best way to deal with a situation where I sometimes have function arguments `f(x1, x2, x3)` and when I sometimes have the function argument `f([x1,x2,x3])`. I think this is actually quite a good question for StackOverflow, so it would be best if you asked this in a new question so it is easily searchable by others.

Comment: Ok Colin, thanks! I'll do it! By the way, I followed your advice concerning the approval of answers here :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many ways to do it. If you want to avoid coding you can use DataFrames package. This is not the fastest solution, but it is short.

Assume you have arrays defined as variables:

```
x = [5.0  3.5
     6.0  3.6
     7.0  3.0]

y = [5.0  4.5
     6.0  4.7
     8.0  3.0]

z = [5.0  4.0
     6.0  3.2
     8.0  4.0]
```

Then you can do:

```
using DataFrames
Matrix(aggregate(DataFrame(vcat(x,y,z)), :x1, sum))
```

The `:x1` part is because by default first column of a `DataFrame` is called `:x1` if you do not give an explicit name to it. In this recipe we convert matrices to a `DataFrame` aggregate them and convert back the result to a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Without extra package, a possible solution can be something like

```
function aggregate(m::Array{<:Number,2}...)

    result=sortrows(vcat(m...))

    n = size(result,1)
    if n <= 1
        return result
    end 

    key_idx=1
    key=result[key_idx,1]

    for i in 2:n
      if key==result[i,1]
          result[key_idx,2:end] += result[i,2:end]
      else
          key = result[i,1]
          key_idx += 1
          result[key_idx,1]     = key 
          result[key_idx,2:end] = result[i,2:end]
      end
    end

    return result[1:key_idx,:]
end
```

Demo:

```
x = [5.0  3.5
     6.0  3.6
     7.0  3.0]

y = [5.0  4.5
     6.0  4.7
     8.0  3.0]

z = [5.0  4.0
     6.0  3.2
     8.0  4.0]

aggregate(x,y,z)
```

Prints:

```
4×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  12.0
 6.0  11.5
 7.0   3.0
 8.0   7.0
```

Note: this solution also works with any number of columns

Comment: Wonderful! Nice solution too! Creating our aggregate function.