# Merge large number of arrays by common column values in julia

Tags: julia, array-merge

Expanding a previous question I put here before, suppose we have a large number of arrays (say 500 arrays), like the following 3 first ones

`5.0  3.5
 6.0  3.6
 7.0  3.0`

`5.0  4.5
 6.0  4.7
 8.0  3.0`

`5.0  4.0
 6.0  3.2
 8.0  4.0`

and so on, stored in one array, so that we have an array of 500 arrays of the type above. I want to merge the 500 arrays into one array, by common values of the first column, calculating the mean values of the corresponding elements of the second column. The result must be the following array:

`5.0  mean of all 5's values
 6.0  mean of all 6's values
 7.0  mean of all 7's values
 8.0  mean of all 8's values`

How can I achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that is ~6 times faster than the answer from @PicaudVincent (based on his input data), but which doesn't sort the keys, so the rows of the return matrix is in arbitrary order:

```
function accumarrays(A::Vector{Matrix{T}}) where {T}
    d = Dict{T, Tuple{T, Int}}()
    for a in A
        for i in indices(a, 1)
            ai = a[i, 1]
            d[ai] = get(d, ai, (zero(T), 0)) .+ (a[i, 2], 1)
        end
    end
    Aout = Matrix{typeof(one(T)/1)}(length(d), 2)
    i = 0
    for (key, val) in d
        Aout[i+=1, 1] = key
        Aout[i, 2] = val[1] / val[2]
    end
    return Aout
end
```

If you need the rows to be sorted, this works, but is just 4-5 times faster:

```
function accumarrays_(A::Vector{Matrix{T}}) where {T}
    d = Dict{T, Tuple{T, Int}}()
    for a in A
        for i in indices(a, 1)
            ai = a[i, 1]
            d[ai] = get(d, ai, (zero(T), 0)) .+ (a[i, 2], 1)
        end
    end
    dkeys = sort!(collect(keys(d)))
    Aout = Matrix{typeof(one(T)/1)}(length(dkeys), 2)
    for i in eachindex(dkeys)
        val = d[dkeys[i]]
        Aout[i, 1] = dkeys[i]
        Aout[i, 2] = val[1] / val[2]
    end
    return Aout
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Speed is indeed always welcome and what I'm looking for!

Comment: And if we want to obtain the standard deviation instead? I tried to adapt the line starting with `d[ai]= get...` with the function `std(..., corrected=false)`, but I was unable to obtain the standard deviation instead of the mean. Even for the mean, isn't it possible to use the `mean` function?

Comment: That's not going to work. The functions `std` and `mean` have to work on collections of numbers, but what my function does, is specifically to avoid building collections, so there is nothing that those functions can operate on. It _is_ possible to do something similar to what I did to get the std. Then you need to keep a running sum of the _squared_ number together with the running sum and the count. At the end, you can calculate the std from there.

Comment: Right. The best is to use the definition of standard deviation. I'll try to modify the line where the sum is computed.

Answer (score 2):

Also back with a slight modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842721/2001017

```
function aggregate(m::Array{<:Array{<:Number,2},1})

    result=sortrows(vcat(m...))

    n = size(result,1)
    if n <= 1
        return result
    end 

    key_idx = 1
    key     = result[key_idx,1]
    count   = 1

    for i in 2:n
      if key == result[i,1]
          result[key_idx,2:end] += result[i,2:end]
          count                 += 1
      else
          result[key_idx,2:end] /= count
          count                  = 1
          key                    = result[i,1]
          key_idx               += 1
          result[key_idx,1]      = key 
          result[key_idx,2:end]  = result[i,2:end]
      end
    end

    result[key_idx,2:end] /= count

    return result[1:key_idx,:]
end
```

**Demo:**

```
x = [5.0  3.5
     6.0  3.6
     7.0  3.0]

y = [5.0  4.5
     6.0  4.7
     8.0  3.0]

z = [5.0  4.0
     6.0  3.2
     8.0  4.0]

a=[x,y,z]
```

---

```
julia> a
3-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 [5.0 3.5; 6.0 3.6; 7.0 3.0]
 [5.0 4.5; 6.0 4.7; 8.0 3.0]
 [5.0 4.0; 6.0 3.2; 8.0 4.0]
```

---

```
julia> aggregate(a)
4×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.0  4.0    
 6.0  3.83333
 7.0  3.0    
 8.0  3.5
```

Comment: Yes! I thought about this extension concerning my last post. Thank you!